# ArgumentError ('1' is not a valid type) in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I am working on a form that has a select list:

```
<%= f.select :type, options_for_select(Property.types), {prompt: "Select Type of Property..."}, class: "form-control" %>
```

`type` is an integer in my database. The `Property.types` is pulling the list from an `enum` attribute in my Property model:

```
enum type: { Type_1: 1, Type_2: 2, Type_3: 3 }
```

For some reason, when submitting the form, I am getting an error:

> ArgumentError ('1' is not a valid type):
>   Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 10ms (ActiveRecord: 4.0ms)

I assume that is because the selected list value is being submitted as a string instead of an integer.

I am using Rails v.5.2.1.

How to solve that issue?

Comment: Please review the trace and include the relevant portion. Ruby on Rails is great about showing you the file, line and character position which raised the error.

Comment: Try changing the select like this `<%= f.select :type, Property.types.map { |key, value| [key.humanize, key] }, {prompt: "Select Type of Property..."}, class: "form-control" %>`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> ArgumentError ('1' is not a valid type)

You should change the `select` like below

```
<%= f.select :type, options_for_select(Property.types.map { |key, value| [key.humanize, key] }), {prompt: "Select Type of Property..."}, class: "form-control" %>
```

Because, this

```
<%= f.select :type, options_for_select(Property.types), {prompt: "Select Type of Property..."}, class: "form-control" %>
```

generates the `select` with `options` like

```
<option value="0">Type_1</option>
<option value="1">Type_2</option>
<option value="2">Type_1</option>
```

So, upon form submit the values of `select` are sent as `"0", "1", "2"` which are **not valid types for the enum** `type`.

And this

```
<%= f.select :type, options_for_select(Property.types.map { |key, value| [key.humanize, key] }), {prompt: "Select Type of Property..."}, class: "form-control" %>
```

generates the `select` with `options` like

```
<option value="Type_1">Type 1</option>
<option value="Type_2">Type 2</option>
<option value="Type_3">Type 3</option>
```

So now the values of `select` are sent as `"Type_1", "Type_2", "Type_3"` which are **valid types for the enum** `type`.

Moreover, `type` is a **reserve word**(which is used in *STI*). I recommend changing it to  something like `property_type`

Comment: It worked. Thanks a lot. Also thanks for the tip on changing the column to "property_type".